# Adding a nudge_y to the data labels of a "Jittered" R ggplot2 graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

I am facing a smal issue concerning positioning labels on an R graph. I made an example with the data available in `ggplot2` package to make it executable.

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

pos <- position_jitter(seed = 1, height = 0.25)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(vs, wt, group = am, label = wt)) +
  geom_jitter(position = pos) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ifelse(wt > 3, wt, "")), position = pos)
```

I used the command `position_jitter` to define jitter and `geom_text_repel` to set data labels. Using `position_jitter` I cannot define a position `nudge_y` of data labels but I woukld like to add to the defined position (`position_jitter(seed = 1, height = 0.25)`) a fixed value, let's say +0.5, so as to shift up systematically every label of a defined value.

Is it possible to make in R something like this?

Thank you in advance for every your reply!

Comment: Wouldn't this be as simple as just using `aes(y = wt + 0.5, label = ifelse(wt > 3, wt, ""))` in the repel layer?

Comment: I see it works, but it is not a 100% good solution because you miss the connecting line label-dot. If the dot is distant from the label, there should be a connecting line between the two to indicate which label refers to. Why you put `y = wt + 0.5` into the aesthetic? Because there, you are defining the y position of the labels?

Comment: Yes, layers normally inherit aesthetics from the global call to `ggplot()`. However, if you set aesthetics in a layer, they overrule aesthetics from the global plot.

Comment: Besides this, it's a pity the line missing.

Comment: Another way to get rid of the problem is to add jitter manually before feeding data to ggplot2. Then you can just use `ggrepel::position_nudge_repel()`.

Comment: Can you write an example simplified code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: comments

You can manually add jitter (random uniform) noise to your datapoints beforehand. Nudging the text then becomes trivial.

```r
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(jit_vs = vs + runif(length(vs), -0.4, 0.4),
         jit_wt = wt + runif(length(wt), -0.25, 0.25)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(jit_vs, jit_wt, group = am, label = wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ifelse(wt > 3, wt, "")), nudge_y = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It works and it is a good solution. I will translate in my official dataframe!