# Adding a nudge_y to the data labels of a "Jittered" R ggplot2 graph - Categorical values

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

Yesterday I posted a question, looking for a special jittered graph a nudge_y on the labels, so as to move them on an upper part of the graph.

[Former question Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69044542/adding-a-nudge-y-to-the-data-labels-of-a-jittered-r-ggplot2-graph)

We were able to fix up my problem, adding jitter to the original dataframe.

Now I am facing something similar, but the y-variable is not qualitative continual, but categorical. Just to make it simple I take the data from `iris` database.

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
attach(iris)

pos <- position_jitter(seed = 1, height = 0.25)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Species, label = Sepal.Width), max.overlaps = Inf) +
  geom_jitter(position = pos) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ifelse(Sepal.Width > 3, Sepal.Width, "")), position = pos)
```

Obtaining this graph

[image]

I would like to define now a `nudge_y` on `geom_text_repel` in order to shift along y-direction only the labels (or also without using `nudge_y` but with a different trick that I do not know). With this kind of variable I cannot add jittering on the dataframe because `Species` is categorical variable.

Using `aes(y = Sepal.Width + 0.5, label = ifelse(Sepal.Width > 3, Sepal.Width, ""))` jitters the labels but they miss the connection with the points:

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works pretty much the same with categorical variables, you just have to make the factor into a numeric variable and then add the labels later:

```r
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)


iris %>% 
  mutate(jit_species = as.numeric(Species) + runif(n(), -0.25, 0.25)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = jit_species, label = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ifelse(Sepal.Width > 3, Sepal.Width, "")),
                  max.overlaps = Inf,
                  nudge_y = .25) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:3, 
                     label = levels(iris$Species))
```

[image]

Comment: It works and it is fine, I will give you this as problem-solving answer for sure. Only one question that I would like to understand: `scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:3, 
                     label = levels(iris$Species))` You set a y scale of continuous values, than you set the three breaks and then  why do you use `levels`?

Comment: Factors consist of two elements: An integer vector and a levels vector. The levels represent the possible realizations of the variable and the integer vector stores the actual values that correspond to the order of the level vector. Meaning in this case specifically, the levels are `c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")`, meaning the setosa is stored as `1`, versicolor as `2` and virginica as `3`. With `as.numeric()` we extract the integer values. Then we jitter them. In `scale_y_continuous()` we then label the axis with the original character values associated with the numeric representation

Comment: `breaks` says where the labels are, and `label` what they say